# Keep track of a user 100% sure

Tags: dynamic, cookies, ip

I am trying to ban users that spam my service by logging their IP and blocking it.
Of course this isn't safe at all, because of dynamic IP addresses.
Is there a way to identify a user that's 100% safe?
I've heard about something called evercookie, but I was easily able to delete that, and I guess that anyone capable of changing their IP can also keep their PC clean..

Are there any other options? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

A cookie will prevent the same browser from visiting your site as long as the user doesn't delete it, or turn off cookies, or use a different browser, or reinstall their browser, or use another machine, etc.

There is no such thing as 100% safe. Spam is an ongoing problem that most websites just have to learn to deal with.

There are numerous highly secure options, mostly relying on multi-factor authentication and physical key generators like the ones RSA markets. But the real question is an economic one. The more draconian the authentication mechanism, the more quickly you kill your website as you scare off all your visitors.

More practical solutions involve CAPTCHA, forum moderation, spam-reporting affordances, etc. One particularly effective technique is to block offending content from every IP address except the one that originated it. That way, the original spammer thinks their content is still there, oblivious to the fact that no one else can see it.

Comment: Ah well, captcha won't work in my case. I have people put some code on their website, through which something is displayed. I log everytime a user sees (or clicks on) MY content on someone's website. Through those loggings I check wheather a user spammed his f5 button or clicked many times on the content.
Currently I just log the IP, but if the user changes their IP, my loggings will go corrupt of course, and I need some way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I get that it's impossible to 100% identify a unique visitor.
What are the things that I could do to:
 - find whether someone (anonymous) is using lots of different proxies to see my content (problem here is that cookies would land on the machine of the proxy? and not the actual visitors PC?)
 - identify unique (anonymous) visitors with a dynamic IP